# List View Header DataBinding Not Working: Xamarin Forms Cross Platform App

Tags: listview, xamarin, header, xamarin.forms

I am developing a iOS/Android combination app using XamarinForms and in a ListView I and trying to put some data. I used a data template within the list view to try to accomplish this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Header="{Binding BindPrayUpPointMessage}" SelectedItem="Handle_ItemSelected" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemSelected">
     <ListView.Header>
     <DataTemplate>
    <StackLayout Padding="10,5,0,5" BackgroundColor="#cccccc">
        <Label Text="Welcome, Logixologist" />
        <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="Small"/>
    </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.Header>
```

I have in the underlying data model a property called `BindPrayUpPointMessage` which returns a value. I am binding the message to the list view data template. Using some online resources but I think I have something wrong.

Here is the model:

```
public PrayUpNavigationItems()
        {

        }

        public string MainPages { get; set; }
        public string CategoryPages { get; set; }
        public static string BindPrayUpPointMessage { get { return PrayUpPointsMessage; } }
        public static string PrayUpPointsMessage;
```

In the code behind of the Page with the list view I have this to set the points:

```
PrayUpPoints = 1765;
        prayupapp.PrayUpNavigationItems.PrayUpPointsMessage = "Total PrayUpPoints: " + PrayUpPoints.ToString();
```

When I run it, the header looks like this:

> [image: Android Version]
>
> [image: iOS Version]

How can I correctly bind the string to a Header in a ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do it this way first of all remove the header tag and bind the label with `BindPrayUpPointMessage` directly.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="stackoverflow.YourPage" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:stackoverflow;">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:YourViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ListView x:Name="listView" SelectedItem="Handle_ItemSelected">
<ListView.Header>
    <StackLayout Padding="10,5,0,5" BackgroundColor="#cccccc">
        <Label Text="Welcome, Logixologist" />
        <Label Text="{Binding BindPrayUpPointMessage}" FontSize="Small"/>
    </StackLayout>               
</ListView.Header>
</ListView>
```

Now tell your view that your property `BindPrayUpPointMessage` has changed

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    string bindPrayUpPointMessage;
    public string BindPrayUpPointMessage
    {
        get { return bindPrayUpPointMessage; }
        set
        {
            bindPrayUpPointMessage = value;

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(BindPrayUpPointMessage)));
        }
    }
}
```

in the code-behind you can set `BindPrayUpPointMessage` directly.

```
public partial class YourPage : ContentPage
{
    public YourPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var ViewModel = new YourViewModel();
        BindingContext = ViewModel;

        var PrayUpPoints = 1765;
        ViewModel.BindPrayUpPointMessage = "Total PrayUpPoints: " + PrayUpPoints.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I ever updated the point total on another page how can I fire the PropertyChanged event for this if I wanted it to refresh the data. Or should I refresh another way. I am hoping to add some code to the `protected override void OnAppearing ()`

Comment: This seems to be total different question. Sign this one as answered and open a new one. Also consider using the mvvm pattern. That means in short words try to leave the view as stupid as possible! But later more!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `DataTemplate` tag and you are good to go

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"SelectedItem="Handle_ItemSelected" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemSelected">
    <ListView.Header>
        <StackLayout Padding="10,5,0,5" BackgroundColor="#cccccc">
            <Label Text="Welcome, Logixologist" />
            <Label Text="{Binding PrayUpPointsMessage}" FontSize="Small"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ListView.Header>
</ListView>
```

Also note I am binding the `PrayUpPointsMessage` directly in the Label.

**UPDATE:**

Your `PrayUpNavigationItems` class has to be updated to something like this:

```
public class PrayUpNavigationItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string MainPages { get; set; }
    public string CategoryPages { get; set; }

    private string prayUpPointsMessage;
    public string PrayUpPointsMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return prayUpPointsMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            prayUpPointsMessage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PrayUpPointsMessage));
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName="")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public PrayUpNavigationItems()
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface with consist in only one event `PropertyChanged`. This has to be called every time a property value changes, only if you want the UI to be notified of such change. In the example above only the changes on the `PrayUpPointsMessage` will be notified, if you need the others properties to do the same you will have to follow the same pattern.

Notice that the property cannot be marked as `static` this is because you need of the class instance to access the `PropertyChanged` so you will  need to actually create and instance in your XAML code behind to be able to  assign the value.

```
var PrayUpPoints = 1765;

var prayUpNavigationItems = new PrayUpNavigationItems();
prayUpNavigationItems.PrayUpPointsMessage = $"Total PrayUpPoints: {PrayUpPoints}";
```

Looking at the class I also notice you'd no longer need the `BindPrayUpPointMessage` property and binding directly to the `PrayUpPointsMessage` should do the job. If you really need it you'd just need to implement the notify for this.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Thanks. That was what I tried first. Binding directly to that or any other string for that matter returns nothing. The static label shows but the binding one doesn't.

Comment: @logixologist it's not updating cause you need to tell it to update. When using binding your ViewModels, in your case `PrayUpNavigationItems` has to implement the I`NotifyPropertyChanged` interface and Notify the UI for changes. Updating my original answer.